# On mobile, page hangs / stutters when scrolling form

Tags: html, ios, forms, user-interface, mobile

I have a page with a form within the rest of the content.

The problem is the page hangs / stutters when I scroll through the form on mobile, particularly iOS. It happens no matter where I place the form in the flow of the content. And in addition to the hang, the page does not 'slide' when swiped vertically.

Here is the html for the form...

```
<div id="authform">
<div class="sectionhead">
<h1 class="blue">Do You Qualify to Use the Device</h1>
</div>
<form action="https://purchase-authorization.net/" method="post">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td style="float:right;text-align: right;font-size: 10px;">
<span class="req-symbol"> * </span> denotes required fields</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="first_name" style="margin-right: 10px;">
<label for="first_name" id="first_name_label" class=""> First Name <span class='req-symbol'>
<strong> * </strong>
</span>
</label>
<input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="" required />
</td>
<td id="last_name">
<label for="last_name" id="last_name_label" class=""> Last Name <span class='req-symbol'>
<strong> * </strong>
</span>
</label>
<input id="last_name" name="last_name" type="text" placeholder="" required />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="email">
<label for="email" id="email_label" class=""> Email <span class='req-symbol'>
<strong> * </strong>
</span>
</label>
<input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="" required />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="full" id="implanted">
<label for="implanted" id="implanted_label" class=""> Do you have a medical device implanted in your head or neck? <span class='req-symbol'>
<strong> * </strong>
</span>
</label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<label class="binary">
<input type="radio" name="implanted" value="Yes" />
<div class="tick">
</div>
<span>Yes</span>
</label>
</td>
<td>
<label class="binary">
<input type="radio" name="implanted" value="No" checked />
<div class="tick">
</div>
<span>No</span>
</label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="full" id="pacemaker">
<label for="pacemaker" id="pacemaker_label" class=""> Do you have a pacemaker? <span class='req-symbol'>
<strong> * </strong>
</span>
</label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<label class="binary">
<input type="radio" name="pacemaker" value="Yes" />
<div class="tick">
</div>
<span>Yes</span>
</label>
</td>
<td>
<label class="binary">
<input type="radio" name="pacemaker" value="No" checked />
<div class="tick">
</div>
<span>No</span>
</label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="full" id="over_21">
<label for="over_21" id="over_21_label" class=""> Are you 21 years of age or older? <span class='req-symbol'>
<strong> * </strong>
</span>
</label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<label class="binary">
<input type="radio" name="over_21" value="Yes" checked />
<div class="tick">
</div>
<span>Yes</span>
</label>
</td>
<td>
<label class="binary">
<input type="radio" name="over_21" value="No" />
<div class="tick">
</div>
<span>No</span>
</label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="full" id="updates">
<label for="updates" id="updates_label" class=""> May the manufacturer email you important device related updates? <span class='req-symbol'>
<strong> * </strong>
</span>
</label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<label class="binary">
<input type="radio" name="updates" value="Yes" checked />
<div class="tick">
</div>
<span>Yes</span>
</label>
</td>
<td>
<label class="binary">
<input type="radio" name="updates" value="No" />
<div class="tick">
</div>
<span>No</span>
</label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: auto;">
<label>Confirm that you are not a bot <span class='req-symbol'>
<strong> * </strong>
</span>
</label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="full">
<input type="hidden" name="addauth">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<br />
<br />
<br />
</div>
```

And here is the CSS...

```
div#authform {
  background:#b6ebff;
}
div#authform #greenbar {
    max-width: 760px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px 0 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    height: 185px;
}
div#authform .site-title {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 32px;
    text-shadow: 0px 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}
div#authform .site-subhead {
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-shadow: 0px 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
div#authform .below-header {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    padding: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
div#authform .site-content {
    width: 900px;
    margin-top: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 5px rgba(0, 1, 1, 0.1);
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #fff;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
div#authform form {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div#authform label {
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
div#authform span.req-symbol {
    color: #ff0000;
}
div#authform input {
    /*margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
    padding: 0.625em 0.4375em;*/
    padding: 0 0.4375em;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
div#authform input, label.binary {
    background-image: none;
    border: none;
    height: 70px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    display: block;
    background: #e9f9ff;
}
div#authform label.binary {
    text-align: center;
}
div#authform label.binary span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
}
div#authform input[type="radio"] {
    visibility: hidden;
}
div#authform input#first_name, div#authform input#last_name {
    width: 235px;
}
div#authform input#email {
    width: 100%;
}
div#authform input#first_name, div#authform input#last_name, div#authform  input#email {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
div#authform #ninja_forms_field_2_div_wrap {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 488px;
}
div#authform td {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*max-width: 250px;*/
}
div#authform td.full {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
div#authform td#last_name {
    float:right;
    width:48%;
}
div#authform td#last_name input {
  /*border-left: 10px solid #b6ebff;*/
}
div#authform td#email {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
}
div#authform td:nth-of-type(2n) {
    float: right;
}
div#authform label input + div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 25%;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background-image: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0315/7737/t/2/assets/tick-circle.png?10653060167534890121);
}
div#authform label input:checked + div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 25%;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    background-image: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0315/7737/t/2/assets/tick_green.png?14586621079243987983);
}
div#authform #submit {
    background: #39b54a;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 0.046875em;
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 0.84375em 0.875em 0.78125em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    cursor: pointer;
    width:100%;
    height: 42px;
}
div#authform .below-header.pay {
    padding: 40px 100px;
}
div#authform div#pa_button {
    cursor: hand;
    max-width: 500px; 
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#417194,#2c4c69);
    border: 4px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
div#authform div#below_pa_button {
    font-size: 12px;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div#authform div#greenfooter {
    height: 60px;
    background: #54b761;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 5px rgba(0, 1, 1, 0.1);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
div#authform td#first_name, div#authform td#last_name {
    width: 100% !important;
    display: block;
    float: left !important;
}
div#authform input#first_name, div#authform input#last_name {
    width: 100% !important;
}
}
```

I've tried hiding the form until everything else loads using display:none until window.load. No help. I've even minified the form html and css without success.

[This](https://fisherwallace-ca.myshopify.com/) is the page where you can see the issue near the bottom of the page.

And [here](https://www.fisherwallace.com/pages/do-you-qualify-to-use-the-device) is a free-standing page that loads and scrolls fine with basically the same form and css.

Appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to CSS solved the issue...

```
overflow-y: scroll!important;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch!important;
```